# Numpad_ENTER not detected in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Using the code in the following example [HERE](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/LogicalKeyboardKey-class.html) The numpad key is detected as expected, however in Android studio, The numpad enter key is not detected even when using this same code.

Can anyone tell me how to get input from the numpad enter key?

Flutter (Channel beta, 2.8.0-3.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-GB)
and
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-GB)
Android SDK version 30.0.3
Android Studio (version 4.2)

**UPDATE**: Flutter team are now aware of this issue
[#93720](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93720)

I have a Customer facing PIN entry device which uses it, as well as a couple of barcode scanners which use it...

**Does anyone know a workaround to trigger any event on numpad_enter key?**
How about through Android method channel?

Comment: Hi @Lewy - can you pleas eadd the relevant code (properly formatted) into the question body?

Comment: Edited the title + added a tag, and left a comment to bring the relevant code into the question body